# Override Yii2 Swiftmailer Recipient

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

I need to override the recipient email for every instance of Swiftmailer's `send()` function throughout my Yii2 application. This is for the purpose of load testing.

Is there an easy way to do this? Or at least a way to do it without editing Swiftmailer's vendor files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for test only why not set `useFileTransport` so emails will be saved in the folder of your choice instead of being sent. To do so configure it like this:

```
'components' => [
    // ...
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport' => true,
    ],
],
```

This will save all emails in the `@runtime/mail` folder, If you want different one set:

```
'mailer' => [
    // ...
    'fileTransportPath' => '@runtime/mail', // path or alias here
],
```

If you want to still send emails and override recipients you can for example extend `yii\swiftmailer\Mailer` class.

```
class MyMailer extends \yii\swiftmailer\Mailer
{
    public $testmode = false;
    public $testemail = 'test@test.com';

    public function beforeSend($message)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSend($message)) {
            if ($this->testmode) {
                $message->setTo($this->testemail);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Configure it:

```
'components' => [
    // ...
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'namespace\of\your\class\MyMailer',
        // the rest is the same like in your normal config
    ],
],
```

And you can use it in the same way you use `mailer` component all the time. When it's time to switch to test mode modify the configuration:

```
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'namespace\of\your\class\MyMailer',
    'testmode' => true,
    'testemail' => 'test222@test.com', // optional if you want to send all to address different than default test@test.com
    // the rest is the same like in your normal config
],
```

With this, every email will be overridden with your recipient address.