# Yii2 mail catcher

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer, mailer

During the development and testing, I want the Yii2 mailer (swiftmailer) not to send emails to actual addresses, but replace it with developers` emails. Is there any setting in config to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `useFileTransport` to `true` in component configuration for the development environment and all emails will not be sent but will be saved as files so you can easily test everything.

Comment: I want email to be send to developers' addresses. It's not a solution

Comment: If so you can use my solution already given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538164/override-yii2-swiftmailer-recipient

Answer (score 0):

You should set configs for prod and dev environment.
Path for dev config (if you have advanced application template): `yourProject/environments/dev/common/config/main-local.php` and for prod: `yourProject/environments/prod/common/config/main-local.php.`

[You may use EmailTarget class for logs.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html)
Example of config for dev environment to reach the clue:

```
return [
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'components' => [
    ...
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        'useFileTransport' => true,//set this property to false to send mails to real email addresses
        //comment the following array to send mail using php's mail function
    ],
    'log' => [
        'targets' =>
            [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\EmailTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error'],
                    'except' => ['yii\web\HttpException:404'],
                    'message' => [
                        'to' => ['example@mail.ru'],
                        'from' => ['yourproject@mail.ru'],
                        'subject' => ' Errors ',
                    ]
                ],
            ],
    ],
],
```

];

And similarly for prod environment but with different emails.

If you don't want to use EmailTarget class you may just set your emails for dev in params config here: `yourProject/environments/dev/common/config/params-local.php.`
And path for prod: `yourProject/environments/prod/common/config/params-local.php`

Params config example:

```
return [
'sendToEmails' => ['email1@mail.ru', 'email2@mail.ru']
];
```

And then you may use the variable in your code this way: `Yii::$app->params['sendToEmails']` to get the array of emails to send messages to.

Don't forget to do `php init` command in your project after compliting your configs.

[You may see the detailed docs about environments here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html).